# Sqlite Select on vxworks

Tags: sqlite, vxworks

Hello I have Database(sqlite3) on vxworks with name: Cards.db
There is a table named Start_Down (time int, type int, card text). I wanted to select the latest card for the selected type (in the query below it is 8). I made a query under windows using Sqlite Browser software.
The query was: "SELECT Card FROM Start_Down WHERE time = (select max(time) from Start_Down WHERE type = 8);" and it was working great there. Now when i am running this query under vxworks it crashes. Do you have any idea what is wrong there? Thank you in advance!

PS. I have tried to make other queries to check sqlite engine and all other queries were working. For example:  "SELECT Card FROM Start_Down WHERE time = (select max(time) from Start_Down);" or "SELECT Card FROM Start_Down WHERE type = 8);"

Comment: The controller restarts just after I run the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. The reason was you have to use the .out file for select query wich is different than .out for query to insert or update